# How to correctly add additional columns using sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, subquery, lateral-join

I'm trying to separate T.Activity_DtTm clock in and clock out values into two separate columns using a subquery. But when I execute the query I get the following error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

**My Query**

```
SELECT E.Str_ID
    ,E.Emp_ID
    ,(E.Last_Nm + ' ' + E.Frst_Nm) AS Name
    ,T.Bus_DT
    ,T.Activity_DtTm
    ,T.Activity_CD
    ,(
        SELECT T.Activity_DtTm
        FROM Timecard T
        WHERE T.Activity_CD = '1'
        ) AS Clock_In
    ,(
        SELECT T.Activity_DtTm
        FROM Timecard T
        WHERE T.Activity_CD = '2'
        ) AS Clock_Out
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Timecard T ON (
        E.Str_ID = T.Str_ID
        AND E.Emp_ID = T.Emp_ID
        )
WHERE T.BUS_DT = '3/01/2007'
ORDER BY E.Str_ID ASC
    ,E.Emp_ID ASC
    ,T.Bus_DT_Seq ASC
```

How can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

I managed to get the query to run using Gordon Linoff suggestion.

But the problem is due to T.Activity_DtTm storing all clock In and Clock Out dates when they are separated in two different columns Clock In and Clock Out will contain null values.

**Current Output**
[image]

**Desired Output**

The output required is to have both clock in and clock out values display on the same row.

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to achieve this with a query?

**Current Query**

```
SELECT E.Str_ID, E.Emp_ID, (E.Last_Nm + ' ' + E.Frst_Nm) AS Name,
   T.Bus_DT, T.Activity_DtTm, T.Activity_CD, 
   (CASE WHEN  T.Activity_CD = '1' THEN T.Activity_DtTm END) as  Clock_In,
   (CASE WHEN  T.Activity_CD = '2' THEN T.Activity_DtTm END) as  Clock_OUT
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Timecard T
ON E.Str_ID = T.Str_ID AND E.Emp_ID = T.Emp_ID
WHERE T.BUS_DT = '3/01/2007'
ORDER BY E.Str_ID ASC, E.Emp_ID ASC, T.Bus_DT_Seq ;
```

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is that ```,(
        SELECT T.Activity_DtTm
        FROM Timecard T
        WHERE T.Activity_CD = '1'
        ) AS Clock_In```
 is going to give you EVERY Activity_DtTm where the Activity_CD = 1 *REGARDLESS* of user. You didn't put the user or date in this subquery. You'll need to add those as an INNER JOIN, and then you'll need to guarantee exactly 1 row by doing one of the following: ```SELECT TOP 1 T.Activity_DtTm``` or ```SELECT MAX(T.Activity_DtTm)```. Alternatively, do what @GMB suggested, because that is much cleaner.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have updated the post and provided sample with the required result

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that you are running SQL Server. In that database, you can use lateral joins. This is a powerful feature, that can be used to execute correlated subqueries in the `from` clause.

```
select 
    e.str_id, e.emp_id, (e.last_nm + ' ' + e.frst_nm) as name, 
    t.bus_dt, t.activity_dttm, t.activity_cd, 
    t1.*, 
    t2.*
from employee e 
inner join timecard t on e.str_id = t.str_id and e.emp_id = t.emp_id
outer apply (select t.activity_dttm as clock_in  from timecard t where t.activity_cd = '1' ) t1
outer apply (select t.activity_dttm as clock_out from timecard t where t.activity_cd = '2') t2 
where t.bus_dt = '20070301'
order by e.str_id, e.emp_id, t.bus_dt_seq
```

You can add more columns to subqueries `t1` and  `t2`, and they will show up in the resultset.

Note that I changed the date filter to use a safer literal date (which assumes that `t.bus_dt` is of a `date`-like database - as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . If you want the values in different columns, just use `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT E.Str_ID, E.Emp_ID, k(E.Last_Nm + ' ' + E.Frst_Nm) AS Name,
       T.Bus_DT, T.Activity_DtTm, T.Activity_CD
       (CASE WHEN  T.Activity_CD = '1' THEN T.Activity_DtTm END) as  Clock_In,
       (CASE WHEN  T.Activity_CD = '2' THEN T.Activity_DtTm END) as  Clock_OUT
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN 
     Timecard T
     ON E.Str_ID = T.Str_ID AND E.Emp_ID = T.Emp_ID
WHERE T.BUS_DT = '20070301'
ORDER BY E.Str_ID ASC, E.Emp_ID ASC, T.Bus_DT_Seq ;
```